# How can I plot Rotation Curves of Spiral Galaxies $v$ (km/s) vs $r$ (kly)?

Tags: astrophysics, orbital-motion, astronomy, galaxy-rotation-curve

I have a formula about Rotation Curves of Spiral Galaxies that I have written below:

$$v(r)=c [L/(2*r)+1/2\cdot c_3+ c_4\cdot\ln(r)]^{1/2}$$

that $c=3\cdot10^8m/s$ is the speed of light and $c_3=2.8\cdot10^{-6}$, $c_4=0.4$, $L=2\cdot10^{12}\cdot G\cdot M_{sun}/c^2$, $G=6.674\cdot10^{-11}m^3/kgs^2$ (Newtonian gravitational
constant) and $M_{sun}=10^{30}kg$.

How can I plot $V(r)(KM/s)$ vs $r(kly)$ (r is given in unit of kly)?

I have to find a figure like the one below. I have written a maple code but the result does not look like the attached figure. Could you please tell me what I should do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you probably haven't dealt with the necessary unit conversions. To get a value in ${\rm km}\,{\rm s}^{-1}$, the argument of the square root should have dimensions of ${\rm km}^2\,{\rm s}^{-2}$. You can ensure this by cleverly multiplying by factors of 1, for instance $1=1000\,{\rm m}/{\rm km}$ (I leave it to you to find the appropriate conversion factors for your equation). Suitably chosen, this can ensure that the units in your equation are consistent.

The logarithm requires some special care, as it's argument must be dimensionless. Usually you'd denote an (I assume) empirically calibrated relation like this something like $\ln(r/{\rm kly})\, {\rm km}^2\,{\rm s}^{-2}$ to make it clear that the equation only holds when $r$ is given in ${\rm kly}$, or else suitably converted to those units.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I try to solve it

Answer (score 0):

The formula is unclear because you are taking the logarithm of a length. The logarithm would depend on which units you use for the length. But the given value of $c_3$ probably assumes that $r$ is in kly.

So... Compute the length $L$ in kly. Convert $c$ to km/s. Then an $r$ measured in kly should give a $v$ in km/s.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed m in kly and c to km/s and r in kly, but again the result is not correct.

Comment: I have changed symbol m  to L.

Comment: When you edit the question after an answer is written, we have to then edit the answer.

Comment: Where did you get the equation from?

Comment: I looked at the paper and don’t see how those equations produce those curves.

Comment: If we take the differential from Equation 27 and put it in Equation 26, we get an equation of velocity vs r

Comment: Yes, I checked your math and didn’t find a mistake. I’m getting a curve with a similar shape but the values of $v$ are several times too large.

Comment: So is there a problem with the article?

Comment: Actually, I’m getting values *much* too large. (And faster than light.) If the article isn’t wrong, it is confusing.

Comment: Me too.Thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: The log term is dominant at large $r$. When $r$ is 140 kly, that term gives $c\sqrt{0.4\ln{140}}$ or $1.4c$.

Comment: Do you convert c in km/s and L (m in paper) in kly?

Comment: Yes. I got 0.00031 kly for m.